# How to fix "Illegal characters in path." in file path?

Tags: c#, path

I ran into an issue with writing a file path correctly to text file. I get an error "Illegal characters in path.".
My incoming file path from a function is

imagePath = "c:\temp\temp\file_name.jpg".(from a function)

Whenever I use the following

```
imagePath = Path.GetFullPath(imagePath);
```

I get the error "Illegal characters in path.". 
The issue here is that "\t" is considered as an illegal character although its part of path. So how could I write this to a text file? I do not have control over such characters in the name.

How to write the full path ?

Here I am adding more details about the function.

```
ServerResponse jsonResult = new ServerResponse();
            try
            {
                jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(strResponse);
                string imagePath = jsonResult.image;

                //    string imagePath = "\"M\"\\a/ry/ h**ad:>> a\\/:*?\"| li*tt|le|| la\"mb.?";
                //      string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

                imagePath = Path.GetFullPath(imagePath);

                File.AppendAllText(PredictFileName, (string)imagePath);
                txtJSONresult.AppendText((String)imagePath.ToString());
                txtJSONresult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtJSONresult.AppendText(strResponse);
                txtJSONresult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                txtJSONresult.AppendText(ex.Message);
                txtJSONresult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Server send the image path as "c:\temp\temp\file_name.jpg" I want to save that path to txt file in local PC. No matter I do I always have "\t" or probably other special characters that considered to be illegal.
string imagePath = jsonResult.image

So whats the right way to write this path to text file regardless of what it has?

Here is the JSON string I get from the server :

```
{"image":"c:\testimage\test.jpg","predictions":[[1.03891e-05, 0.0128408, 0.914102, 9.68333e-05, 0.0729495]]}
```

Comment: _imagePath = @"c:\temp\temp\file_name.txt"_

Comment: But if your function is returning an incorrect path constant then you should fix the function. It would be useful to see this function

Comment: So if this string comes from another method, then the `\t` is not the problem (if you see this in the debugger window, it's already re-escaped). Examine the string you get character by character to find out if they are what they look like (maybe it's some strange unicode character)..

Comment: Still you haven't shown how the _strReponse_ is created. The code that creates that variable should be fixed if it returns a string path without proper escaping. When you receive the malformed string is too late. (unless you are willing to build a byte by byte parser)

Comment: If some other function is passing you an invalid path, then just throw an exception and document the fact that the path they pass you must be valid. Otherwise, show the code that's generating the path. `@"c:\temp\temp\file_name.jpg"` is not invalid.

Comment: `var invalid = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Union(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()); Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(imagePath.Intersect(invalid)));` should show you the illegal characters in the `imagePath` string.

Comment: It removes"\t" from my path. Then my path is no longer valid.

Comment: The path was not valid to start with if it has a tab character in it. If you're generating the path, then you have control over that. Otherwise, throw an exception and make the client fix it.

Comment: Yes, but that could be a posibility if the files are in folder with "t" or file name starting with  a "t".

Comment: So in C#, it is not valid to have a file name or folder name  starting with "t" ?

Comment: Come on, you know that's not true. Folders and files are allowed to start with `t`. Please show a reproducible sample of how you're generating the path string.

Comment: Here is the JSON string I get form the server : {"image":"c:\testimage\test.jpg","predictions":[[1.03891e-05, 0.0128408, 0.914102, 9.68333e-05, 0.0729495]]}

Comment: I will change the server response with "\\" : (it works ){"image":"c:\\testimage\\test.jpg","predictions":[[1.03891e-05, 0.0128408, 0.914102, 9.68333e-05, 0.0729495]]}

Comment: We have told you this from the start. The path is wrongly built. If you build a C# string with a \t this means horizantal tab. If you want the \ character to be the path separator you need to double it or put the @ verbatim character

Answer (score -1):

**Fixing from server side**

Ensure proper string formats are sent:

```
"C:\\doubleSlash\\paths"

@"C:\singleWith\atSymbol"
```

**Fixing from client side and no server control**

Masage data by replacing invalid characters with correct counterparts if possible, otherwise contact service provider about server side solution ;]

Comment: If the OP ended up using the solutions we were giving him the entire time... perhaps down-voting those answers is a bit unwarranted. **puts on thinking face**... lol